# lambda row function with if else statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe `df` and an array of datetimes `holidays`

```
df.head()

date    hour    count   Relative Humidity   Temperature Precipitation   dow
0   2019-07-01  0   672 57.64   71.8    0.0 Monday
1   2019-07-01  1   359 61.61   70.8    0.0 Monday
2   2019-07-01  2   197 61.63   69.8    0.0 Monday
3   2019-07-01  3   115 63.32   69.0    0.0 Monday
4   2019-07-01  4   168 67.91   67.9    0.0 Monday

df.dtypes

date                  object
hour                   int64
count                  int64
Relative Humidity    float64
Temperature          float64
Precipitation        float64
dow                   object
dtype: object

holidays

[datetime.date(2019, 9, 2), datetime.date(2019, 7, 4)]
```

My goal is to create a new column that indicates whether or not the date is a workday but the following if else statement throws an error:

```
df['is_workday'] = df.apply(lambda row: False if (row['dow'] in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') | pd.to_datetime(row['date'],  format='%Y-%m-%d') in holidays) else True)

KeyError: 'dow'
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `df.apply(...)` applies on columns. To apply your lambda on each row, specify:

```
df.apply(..., axis=1)
```

Aside from that, this looks very inefficient and can be made much faster without any lambda. A more efficient method is to vectorize your logic:

```
cond_wkend = df['dow'].isin({'Saturday', 'Sunday'})
cond_holdy = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).isin(holidays)

df['is_workday'] = ~(cond_wkend | cond_holdy)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried including `axis=0` but still get the same error.  What could be done to make this statement more efficient?

Comment: sorry, my bad, I corrected: I meant `axis=1`.

Comment: `axis = 1` throws a slightly different error: 

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'Timestamp'` - however using `or` works.  

@Pierre What could be done about efficiency here?

Comment: right, use `or` instead of `|`. The former is a regular boolean or, the latter is bitwise operation e.g. on Series. I was just commenting on your initial error.

Comment: see my updated answer re. efficiency; for large DataFrames, you'll be amazed how much faster vectorized operations are. And BTW, in that case, `|` is the correct operator (it's `or` for `Series`).